# Is there a Cordova plugin for Google Analytics iOS SDK v3?

Tags: cordova, google-analytics-sdk

I have been using the [GAPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin) for some time for basic event tracking; it works great.  Now we want to take advantage of [Google's remarketing program](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453998?hl=en) that I believe requires IDFA information sent to Google.

I believe the correct way to do this for in the iOS ecosystem is to use SDKv3 for iOS and enable IDFA as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#initialize).

Ultimately, my question is am I right about what I need to do in order to gather information for the purposes of Google's Remarketing and if so does a plugin already exist?  When it is all said and done I need to have this working on iOS and Android.

Comment: be aware that you can't submit an app using IDFA if it doesn't have ads. About using SDKv3, open an issue on the plugin, maybe they update it

Comment: Thank you, I am starting to gather that using the Google Conversion Tracking SDK for what I am trying to do which is the remarketing for ourselves.  The two SDKs and the way that they talk about remarketing is confusing at least for me.